# Не могу сменить layout в Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

В контроллере хочу сменить layout с main на error. Для этого пишу

```
$this->layout='error'; 
return $this->render('deny');
```

Но все равно ищет файл deny.php в main. Почему не переключается на error?

Answer (score 3):

Для изменения layout'а достаточно определить в контроллере свойство `$layout`.

Пример:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public $layout = 'post';

    // ...
}
```

[Источник](https://yiiframework.com.ua/ru/doc/guide/2/structure-views/#using-layouts).

Изменение layout'а не означает, что будет изменена директория, в которой будут содержаться view-элементы контроллера. Для того, чтобы изменить директорию в которой будут содержаться view-элементы контроллера, необходимо внутри контроллера определить свойство `$viewPath` (аналогично примеру выше) или вызвать метод `setViewPath()` в теле одного из действий контроллера.

Comment: например, у меня в папке frontend/views/error есть файл error.php. когда в SiteController я пишу render('error') - оно ищет файл error.php в папке frontend/views/site. а я хочу что бы он искал в папке frontend/views/error. Как вы описали выше - будет работать?

Comment: @Diefair , да, в таком случае вам нужно указать новый `viewPath` в контроллере.